# How do I make my modified Intellij 'intention' available to my colleagues?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have modified an Intellij 'intention'. (I changed the initialization of the JUnit test class).

How do I make this available to other members of my organization? We are all working on the same Intellij 'project', but I believe that these changes are on a per-user, not per-project basis. (If there is a way to make the changes apply only to one project, I would prefer that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File` | `Export Setting` / `File` | `Import Settings`.

Are more robust way would be to use the [Settings Repository plug-in](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/settings-repository.html).

Templates are stored in the [%CONFIG%](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) directory, `fileTemplates` subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

To export the file, you set the 'Schema:' pulldown in the upper right corner of 'Settings->Editor->File and Code Templates->Code tab' to 'Project' This will cause IDEA to create a folder PROJECT/.idea/fileTemplates/code, and put your modified file there. Details are in:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/file-and-code-templates.html#d2040410e142